# Tensor structure on category of symmetric monoidal categories, $\mathsf{SymMonCat}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathsf{SymMonCat}$ denote the category with objects symmetric monoidal categories and morphisms lax symmetric monoidal functors. Can $\mathsf{SymMonCat}$ be endowed with a "tensor" product that makes it a (symmetric) monoidal category?

I've been thinking that maybe the product between categories could be a candidate, but I can't find anywhere something to back up this claim (probably because it isn't quite true). Any comments, references and answers are very welcome.

Comment: If the cartesian product exists then it defines a symmetric monoidal structure. But I think people are usually more interested in a symmetric monoidal _closed_ structure, and the cartesian product isn't it.

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks for your comment. I'm not looking specifically for closed monoidal categories. Tbh, I came across the notion of monoidal monad functor and since any symmetric monoidal category defines a bicategory, if $\mathsf{SymMonCat}$ is monoidal, one can have the notion of lax monoidal monad functor $\mathcal{F}: \mathsf{SymMonCat} \to \mathsf{SymMonCat}$. Does this sound right you think, to I'm missing something important?

Comment: I think there is a tensor product of symmetric monoidal categories, which is a categorified form of the [tensor product of commutative monoids](https://b-ok.cc/book/2829969/f3ae82). I don't know a reference that goes through all the details of checking this works, but I'm sure you can work them out if this construction is what you want. (Or you can just assume that everything works out fine; like it does in the $1$-categorical case.)